# select rows based on value of column and distinct column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select row that have a distinct store location based on the number of store, the example shown as below:

```
id   | item_name   | number_of_store| store_location|
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
|  3 | margarine | 2              | QLD         |
|  4 | margarine | 2              | NSW         |
|  5 | wine      | 3              | QLD         |
|  6 | wine      | 3              | NSW         |
|  7 | wine      | 3              | NSW         |
|  8 | laptop    | 1              | QLD         |
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
```

The desired result shown below:

```
id   | item_name   | number_of_store| store_location|
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
|  3 | margarine | 2              | QLD         |
|  4 | margarine | 2              | NSW         |
|  5 | wine      | 3              | QLD         |
|  6 | wine      | 3              | NSW         |
|  8 | laptop    | 1              | QLD         |
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Where I don't care which id column value is returned. What would be the required SQL?

Comment: Not caring can be symptomatic of poor design - you *should* care!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT id, item_name ,number_of_store, store_location
FROM tab
GROUP BY  item_name ,number_of_store, store_location;
-- will work if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled
```

Otherwise you need [`ANY_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) or aggregate function like `MIN` :

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(id) AS id, item_name ,number_of_store, store_location
FROM tab
GROUP BY  item_name ,number_of_store, store_location;
```

**[DB-Fiddle.com Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/th4una3kHUZZtE2qu5RgKW/0)**